# How to copy Excel text and keep line breaks

Tags: excel, copy-paste, excel-2013

I have an Excel (2013) spreadsheet that contains multiline text in some of the cells.

Word-wrap is enabled for those cells, so they appear with line breaks correctly. However, the cells in question are protected (and I don't have the password), so I can't click into the edit box to copy from there.

If I use Ctrl-C to copy to the clipboard, then paste into Notepad, then all the line breaks are removed and double quotes are placed around the text.

How can I copy out the text and keep the line breaks?

Comment: Hmm, Google Spreadsheets exhibits the exact same behavior... however, doing this removes the cell protection, allowing me to click into the edit box and copy out the text that way. Good enough, I guess. Though still a pain to copy out multiple (i.e. hundreds) of cells...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notepad doesn't interpret line breaks as cleverly as more fully-featured text editors. Your best bet is probably to try copy/pasting into either Wordpad, or to download something like Notepad++ (https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/) and paste into that first.

This answer does a nice job of further explaining the issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/362087/notepad-ignoring-linebreaks

Comment: You're right. Both Wordpad and Notepad++ work fine. Interestingly, Notepad++ adds double quotes around the text but Wordpad does not. Thanks!